# Не работает php artisan

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Написал свой проект на laravele. Захотел обновить миграции, удалил все таблицы и хочу сделать миграцию. Пишу в консоль php artisan migrate, и выдает ошибку: In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shop.goods' doesn't exist (SQL: select categories.name as name, COUNT(goods.id) as count, categories.id as id from `goods` left
  join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `goods`.`category_id` group by `categories`.`name`, `categories`.`id`)

In Connection.php line 326:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shop.goods' doesn't exist

То есть, почему-то консольное приложение лезет в мое веб приложение, и из-за ошибки я не могу сделать миграции.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Проверь свои миграции. Возможно ты нарушил порядок создания связей между таблицами, вот и ругается, что базовая таблица не существует

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть несколько... Проверьте настройки подключения к бд в `.env`, ну и конечно наличие файла миграций. На будущее совет - никогда не удаляйте таблицы в бд "руками", в Laravel для этого есть соответствующие инструменты:

```
migrate:refresh   Сбросить и повторно запустить все миграции
migrate:reset     Откат всех миграций базы данных
migrate:rollback  Откат последней миграции базы данных
migrate:status    Показывать статус каждой миграции
```

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем проблема, в AppServiceProvider у меня были запросы к бд, их закомментировал и сделал миграции. Всем спасибо, кто откликнулся